# theme color issues after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I installed the mac os snow leopard theme when I used ubuntu 12.04. All went well and the result was really awsome. However since I upgraded to ubuntu 12.10 I have an issue with the selected item color: it doesn't show the way it should (just the blue item color and the item highlighted),the selected item also shows a ligh gray regtangular form and the text is white with a blue ligning. It is difficult to explain and it is a shame I cannot upload a pic, but one thing is sure it is ugly.

Tx for the help

Comment: Upload an image elsewhere and then edit your question to include the link to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Go into Unity dash home, search for "Appearance", change theme to something different and then change back to what you were using.

Mine didn't have anything selected but now has "Ambiance (default)". Seems to have fixed the problem for me.